# automation error catastrophic failure with user check code on open

Tags: vba

I have some VBA code that checks a person's job title before allowing someone to edit the document.  After adding this code in I occasionally get an "Automation Error Catastrophic Failure" message only when opening the spreadsheet. As far as I can tell it does not damage any part of the workbook, and you just have to exit the command debugger twice before it opens. Obviously others at work see this message and overreact to it. Please see my functions that activate when opening the workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Sheets("Start Here").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    If Usercheck() = True Then
        ProtectionOff
    Else
        ProtectionOff
        Range("A1:V260").Locked = True
        ProtectionOn
    End If
End Sub
```

```
Function Usercheck() As Boolean
    Dim user As String
    Dim title As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    user = UserName()

    title = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(user, 
    Sheets("BaseTables").Range("tblStaff[[#All],[Username]:[Title1]]"), 2, False)

    If Left(title, 20) = "Technical Specialist" Then
        Usercheck = True
    ElseIf Left(title, 19) = "Engineering Manager" Then
        Usercheck = True
    ElseIf Left(title, 9) = "Team Lead" Then
        Usercheck = True
    Else
        Usercheck = False
    End If

    Exit Function

    ErrorHandler:
    Usercheck = False

End Function
```

```
Public Function UserName()
    UserName = Environ$("UserName")
End Function
```

Comment: Please add definitions of ProtectionOn and Off and some sample of tblStaff data

Comment: @RicardoDiaz sorry, left that one. Its just a quick sub to keep the password in one spot. ProtectionOff is similar 


`Sub ProtectionOn() 
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="*****", AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True 
End Sub`

Comment: table is pretty standard, just a list of names, user names and titles

Comment: I tried adding this loop to the workbook open sub, but still got the error 
    `Application.Calculate`
    `Do Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone`
    `DoEvents`
    `Loop`

Comment: As the only code you have in Workbook_Open is a sheet selection, it doesn't seem to be causing the "Automation Error". Questions: 1) Does your project compile? 2) What happens if you copy the code to another workbook and open a new Excel instance and run it?

Please have a look at this answer: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/automation-error-catastrophic-failure-problem-with/7dec2412-6cab-4c30-9bfd-c522bf38c8ad